# Assembly.Load vs Assembly.LoadFrom Casting (object must implement iconvertible)

Tags: c#, assembly.load

I want to load an assembly for the purposes of a plug-in functionality whereby the loaded dll may be reloaded without restarting the application. I understand the easiest way to do this is to load the assembly using:

```
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes("myDerivedClass.dll"));
```

rather than:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("myDerivedClass.dll");
```

However, when I used Assembly.Load instead of `Assembly.LoadFrom`, I get the error

> object must implement iconvertible" when executing the following cast:

```
dynamic classObj = Convert.ChangeType(myBaseClassObject, type);
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong / what is different between `Load` and `LoadFrom` to give this error?

Comment: where do myBaseClassObject, type come from? Your are performing an invalid cast, that is why you get the error, this has nothing to with using Load or LoadFrom. Provide more code please.

Comment: The cast works fine with Load. I will post a minimal working example later.

Comment: Using Load(byte[]) is fraught with trouble.  The assembly doesn't have a loading context.  An expensive word that means that the CLR doesn't get any help to locate dependent assemblies.  It is also quite inefficient, the backing storage for the assembly must be allocated in the paging file and can't come from the memory-mapped file.  Don't do it.

Comment: I was only doing this as I want to have a 'plugin" capability which requires DLLs to be modified and reloaded without restarting the application